# Search via NDC api and brand name outputs different results

Tags: openfda, drugs

I was trying to search information about Advil so I tried two ways

Search by drug name:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil

Search by ndc code: https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:0573-0134

In second link output I could get lot of information about the drug where as first link doesn't provide much information about the drug.
Example fields found in second link but missing in first link
dosage_form
active_ingredients
many more fields

Is it expected to work like that? If so, would you help out me with your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. The issue is that Drug Adverse Event (FAERS) records do not always identify a *specific* drug product associated with the adverse event -- as you can see from your example the AE record merely refers to the drug by its generic name "Ibuprofen", which of course matches many specific drug products. It is infeasible for us to determine the specific NDC; hence the long list within the `openfda` section.

The second link you provided identifies one specific drug product by its NDC; hence more fields within the `openfda` section.

Comment: Thanks Denis. So it seems like to get accurate results based on drug, search by NDC is optimal solution